# Prioritize JOIN on multiple columns with an OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to track the source of comments on a blog site and my question relates to priority JOINing on multiple columns with an `OR` statement.

The comments table:

```
      Column        |          Type
--------------------+-------------------------
 id                 | integer
 text               | character varying(1024)
 session_source_id  | integer
 user_source_id     | integer
```

If I have a query like so:

```
SELECT s.type, COUNT(c.id) FROM comments c
   LEFT JOIN sources s ON (c.session_source_id = s.id OR c.user_source_id = s.id) 
GROUP BY 1;
```

There are situations where we know the user source but NOT the session source (which is why I used `OR`), but I want to prioritize the session_source_id *if* we also have a user_source_id *and* those two ids differ.

(there are also situations where we don't know either sources and both columns are null, hence the `LEFT JOIN`)

Does that query prioritize the JOIN on session_source_id since it's listed first in the joining `OR` statement? How does Postgres handle OR conditionals in JOIN statements?

Comment: Using `OR` *both* records are selected.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Right, that's the goal. But what if session_source_id != user_source_id, how does it prioritize which one to join on?

Comment: It doesn't prioritize. The query in this cases will return *2* records, one for `session_source_id` and another one for `user_source_id`.

Comment: I *think* a simple coalesce would work for you - `LEFT JOIN sources s  ON s.id = COALESCE(c.session_source_id, c.user_source_id)`

Comment: @GarethD Yep, the COALESCE was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting GarethD's comment as answer and Wiki, so that it won't be lost:

Try COALESCE instead of OR...

```
LEFT JOIN sources s 
ON s.id = COALESCE(c.session_source_id, c.user_source_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `OR` won't prioritize the conditions, if both conditions are true, both records will be returned. 
If you want any priority, you can use `CASE EXPRESSION`  which will break the moment a condition is met :

```
SELECT s.type, COUNT(c.id) FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN sources s 
 ON (CASE WHEN c.session_source_id = s.id THEN 1
          WHEN c.user_source_id = s.id THEN 1
          ELSE 0
     END = 1) 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: This query actually returns the same results as the one I listed in my question... GarethD's suggestion of using `COALESCE` solved my problem.